# Refer to other CmdLets with module prefix in PowerShell documentation

Tags: powershell

When I write comment based help in a PowerShell CmdLet ps1 script,
that is contained in a module, is it possible to refer to other
CmdLets in the same module so that the resulting output to the user
will print the name of the referred CmdLet when imported with a
*prefix*?

So for example, if I write my comment based help like this:

```
function Get-Thing {
<#

.SYNOPSIS

Get the thing.

.DESCRIPTION

The Get-Thing CmdLet will get a thing.

#>
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(...)
```

and the user imports the module using a prefix:

```
Import-Module -Prefix My
```

Then I want the help to print the CmdLet name `Get-Thing` in the description field as `Get-MyThing`, honoring the module prefix value that the user provided:

```
> help Get-MyThing

NAME
    ...

SYNOPSIS
    ...

SYNTAX
    ...

DESCRIPTION
    This Get-MyThing CmdLet will get a thing.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NAME` and `SYNTAX` sections will be automatically updated to include the prefix when you use one. It's not possible to change it if you use it elsewhere in the help text because you cannot embed variables in a comment.

I would just suggest avoiding using the cmdlet name elsewhere where you can, although you'll generally want to in Examples and that will then be unchanged. However at least with the NAME and SYNTAX sections being accurate that should help users self-correct.

The only other way I can think to do it would be to have external help files or placeholders in the comments that are rewritten as the module is loaded by using PowerShell to read and edit the files, but the effort required doesn't seem worthwhile.

Comment: I just find it to be an odd omission to exclude the documentation part from the prefix transformation when importing a module, especially the EXAMPLES section, perhaps.  Referring other CmdLets in the comment based help and help topic files is important and makes a difference for users, IMHO.